# Sleep after yield inside an object method is not working python

Tags: python

I want to monitor my servers after every few seconds. I have a generator inside an object method which will return overall metrics and after that it should wait for a while and check again:

```
def ping_servers(self):
    while True:
        all_server_metrics = {}
        for server in self.servers:
            response = requests.get(server, timeout=self.timeout_secs)
            server_metrics = {
                'response_time': response.elapsed.total_seconds(),
                'response_code': response.status_code,
            }
            all_server_metrics[server] = server_metrics
        yield json.dumps(all_server_metrics)
        time.sleep(self.period_secs)
```

Here it will not sleep at all. But if I put `time.sleep()` at the beginning of the while loop it will sleep for a given period of time. What could be the reason, why it is not sleeping?

This is the code where I call above method:

```
monitoring = MonitoringService(period_secs=30, timeout_secs=5)

while True:
    ping_results = next(monitoring.ping_servers())
    print(ping_results)
```

Comment: You keep calling `monitoring.ping_servers()` over again and again in your while loop, creating *a new generator*, just use `for result in monitoring.ping_servers(): print(result)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it works!!! why don't you post it as an answer?